# etson Nano Power LED Not Illuminated, USB Type-B Port Unresponsive

Tags: c++

I own a Jetson Nano, and recently, I have encountered a problem where the power LED is not illuminated, and the USB Type-B port is not functioning as expected. Despite the device being powered on, I am unable to establish connectivity through the USB port. I have thoroughly checked the power supply, connections, and inspected the board for any visible damage, but the issue persists.

I have taken the following steps in an attempt to troubleshoot the problem:

Verified the power supply meets the specifications (5V/4A).
Checked the power connector for a secure fit.
Physically inspected the board for any signs of damage.
Tested with an alternative power source.